# ASP.NET MVC - Html.Action Sending Empty List

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using Ajax to populate a partial view in my web application. This partial view contains a link to download a PDF file based upon the data that is currently in the table / List<> of the model.

The partial view is as follows:

```
    @model Inspection_Reports.ViewModel.SummaryReportViewModel

<table id="summaryReportTable" class="table-condensed table-striped">
    <thead><tr><td>Inspector</td><td>Attendant</td><td>Property</td><td>Room Number</td><td>Date</td><td>HK Score</td><td>Maint. Score</td></tr></thead>
    <tbody id="resultsContainer">

        @foreach (var report in @Model.reportsList)
        {

            <tr><td>@report.inspect.empName</td><td>@report.attendant.empName</td><td>@report.location.locName</td><td>@report.room</td><td>@report.endTime</td><td>@report.hkDisplay</td><td>@report.mainDisplay <input type='hidden' name='reportId[i]' /></td></tr>


        }

    </tbody>
</table>


@Html.ActionLink("Export as PDF", "GenerateSummaryPDF",  new { summary = @Model.reportsList  })
```

GenerateSummaryPDF method:

```
      public FileResult GenerateSummaryPDF(List<report_summary> summary)      {


        Document doc = pdfWorker.readyDocument("Inspection Report, Generated " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));
        pdfWorker.createSummaryReport(doc, summary);
       pdfWorker.savePDF(doc, String.Format("{0}/Inspection_Summary_{1}.pdf", @"C:\Users\Khandokar\Desktop", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")));
       return File(String.Format("{0}/Inspection_Summary_{1}.pdf", @"PATH", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")), "application/pdf", "Inspection.pdf");
```

The problem is that, when the GenerateSummaryPDF is called, the summary list is empty. The list is not null, but merely has no items in it.

However, I am not sure why this is the case. When I click the export link, there is data in Model.reportsList; it is visible in the table and further verified by setting a breakpoint.

The parent view:

```
    @model Inspection_Reports.ViewModel.SummaryReportViewModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Report Summaries</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Summary Reports</h2>
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-md-2">Start Date: </label><div class="col-md-4"><input class="form-control summaryFilter" type='text' value="@Model.fromDate" name='startDate' id='startDate' /></div><label class="control-label col-md-2">End Date: </label><div class="col-md-4"><input type='text' value="@Model.toDate" class='form-control summaryFilter' name='endDate' id='endDate' /></div></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Filter By: </label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <select class="form-control summaryFilter" name="filterTypeList" id="filterTypeList">
                    <option value="">Select...</option>
                    <option value="Property">Property</option>
                    <option value="Attendant">Attendant</option>
                    <option value="Inspector">Inspector</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Filter Selection: </label><div class="col-md-4">
                <select class="form-control summaryFilter" name="filterSelectionList" id="filterSelectionList"></select>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
    <div id="reportResults">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("SummaryPartialView", Model);}
    </div>
    @section scripts {
        <script src="~/Scripts/ajaxReports.js"></script>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

The methods used to populate the partial view (based largely on this article: https://cmatskas.com/update-an-mvc-partial-view-with-ajax/)

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetSummaryReports(string fromDate, string toDate, string filterType, string filterValue)
    {
        DateTime from = Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate);
        DateTime to = Convert.ToDateTime(toDate);
        Int32 filterValID = Int32.Parse(filterValue);

        SummaryReportViewModel vm = await GetSummaryVM(from, to, filterType, filterValID);
        return PartialView("SummaryPartialView", vm);
    }


    private async Task<SummaryReportViewModel> GetSummaryVM(DateTime from, DateTime to, string filterType, int filterValID)
    {
        SummaryReportViewModel vm = new SummaryReportViewModel();
        to = to.AddDays(1);

        var reports = dbContext.report_summary.Where(r => r.endTime <= to && r.endTime >= from);
        if (filterType.Equals("Property"))
        {
          reports =  reports.Where(r => r.locationID == filterValID);
        }
        else if (filterType.Equals("Attendant"))
        {
            reports = reports.Where(r => r.employee == filterValID);
        }
        else
        {
            reports = reports.Where(r => r.inspector == filterValID);
        }

        vm.reportsList = reports.ToList<report_summary>();
        return vm;
    }
```

The Ajax

```
    $(".summaryFilter").change(function () {
    var fromDate = $("#startDate").val();
    var toDate = $("#endDate").val();


    var filterType = $("#filterTypeList").val();
    var filterValue = $("#filterSelectionList").val();

    if (filterValue != null || typeof (filterValue) != typeof (undefined)) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "GetSummaryReports?fromDate=" + fromDate + "&toDate=" + toDate + "&filterType=" + filterType + "&filterValue=" + filterValue,
            type: 'get',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#reportResults").html(data);
            },

        });
    }
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You cannot send a collection of complex objects to a GET method using `new { summary = @Model.reportsList  }` - look at the url it generates to understand. But what is the point of sending back the whole model your just sent to the view back the server unchanged (that is just degrading performance). Just send back the 4 parameters you used to generate the view so that you reconstruct the `List<report_summary>` that you need to create the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking a bit much of a Get method - you should instead switch to a form that Posts to allow model binding to handle your complex list object.